# Proving if $ \Gamma_{2}(R)\smallsetminus J(R) $ is a forest then it is either totally disconnected or a star graph

Tags: abstract-algebra, graph-theory, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

These days I am reading the research paper *[Graphs associated to co-maximal ideals
of commutative rings](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869308002901)* by Hsin-Ju Wang.

In this paper, $ R $ denotes a commutative ring with the identity element. $ \Gamma(R) $ is a graph with vertices as elements of $ R $, where two distinct vertices $ a $ and $ b $ are adjacent if and only if $ Ra + Rb = R $. $ \Gamma_{2}(R)$ denotes the subgraph of $ \Gamma(R) $ which consists of non-unit elements. In addition, $ J(R) $ is the Jacobson radical of $ R $ .

I am trying to understand the proof of Theorem 3.5. Theorem 3.5. states

> The following are equivalent for $ \Gamma_{2}(R)\smallsetminus J(R) $.
>
> (i). $ \Gamma_{2}(R)\smallsetminus J(R) $ is a forest.
>
> (ii). $ \Gamma_{2}(R)\smallsetminus J(R) $ is either totally disconnected or a star graph.
>
> (iii). $ R $ is either a local ring which is not a field or $ R $ is isomorphic to $ \mathbb{Z}_{2}\times F $, where $ F $ is a field.

[image]

Unfortunately, I can't understand the cases $ (i)\Rightarrow (ii) $ and $ (iii)\Rightarrow (i) $.

Can anyone please explain me how to show if $ \Gamma_{2}(R)\smallsetminus J(R) $ is a forest then it is either totally disconnected or a star graph and if $ R $ is either a local ring which is not a field or $ R $ is isomorphic to $ \mathbb{Z}_{2}\times F $, where $ F $ is a field then $ \Gamma_{2}(R)\smallsetminus J(R) $ is a forest ?

Any hints/ideas are much appreciated.

Thanks in advance for any replies.

Comment: You should point out where exactly you are stuck. For instance, in my opinion, the proof of $(i)\Rightarrow(ii)$ it's pretty straightforward and the author gives enough details.

Comment: @user26857 I really appreciate your advice. I understood my mistakes. In the proof of $(i)\Rightarrow(ii)$, I'm stuck on the proving "if $ R $ has no nontrivial idempotents then $ a-b-a^{2}-b^{2}-a $ is a cycle". Also I'm stuck with showing "$ (1,0)-(a,1)-(b,1)-(1,0) $" and "there is an element $ a\in \mathfrak{m}^{*} $, so that $ (0,1)-(1,0)-(a,1)-(1+a,0)-(0,1) $". Sir, could you help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(i)\Rightarrow(ii)$ If $Ra+Rb=R$ then $Ra^i+Rb^j=R$ for all $i,j\ge 1$.

Next $(R_1\times R_2)(1,0)+(R_1\times R_2)(a,1)=R_1\times R_2$, $(R_1\times R_2)(a,1)+(R_1\times R_2)(b,1)=R_1\times R_2$ since $a+b=1_{R_1}$, and $(R_1\times R_2)(b,1)+(R_1\times R_2)(1,0)=R_1\times R_2$. (For checking all these try to write $(1,1)$ as a linear combination of the given pairs with coefficients in $R_1\times R_2$).

For the last claim proceed as I did before.

Comment: Thanks. Now I'm stuck on the line "$(R_1\times R_2)(1,0)+(R_1\times R_2)(a,1)=R_1\times R_2$". Next line is ok.

Comment: @Tgymasb $(1,0)(1,0)+(0,1)(a,1)=(1,1)$

Comment: Thanks. Now it is clear to me.